# Filter dataframe with condition where all substrings in a column start with particular value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below data

```
   system_id           software_versions
0       1001          ['VA100', 'VB101']
1       1002          ['VA100', 'VA101']
2       1003          ['VA100', 'VB102','VC101']
```

I need to return rows which has **software_versions** beginning with **VA** only.

In this example, only second row matches this criteria, as it contains versions VA100 and VA101.

But other rows have some other version which is not starting with **VA**

**Expected output**

```
   system_id   software_versions
1       1002  ['VA100', 'VA101']
```

I began with this code. I'm not able to proceed further as how I can achieve this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1001,"['VA100', 'VB101']"], [1002,"['VA100', 'VA101']"], [1003,"['VA100', 'VB102','VC101']"]],columns=['system_id', 'software_versions'])
```

**Note**: Actual data will come from a csv file, it has more than 1000 entries. I have provided the exact sample data here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is use generator for test if all values in list starting by `VA` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import ast

df['software_versions'] = df['software_versions'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df = df[df['software_versions'].map(lambda x: all(y.startswith('VA') for y in x))]
print (df)
   system_id software_versions
1       1001    [VA100, VA101]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. Works exactly as I wanted.  `ast.leteral_eval` is a new learning for me.